# Assets and Channel Form upload only

Tags: assets, safecracker, channel-form

I wondered if it was possible to have a straight-to-upload feature for safecracker (channel form) uploads? On the front end, I'd want to bypass the 'browse' section and only allow users to upload an image (with progress bar) and add/edit their meta data without revealing the other files on the system.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Tim,

currently this is not possible, but we do have some interesting ideas that would allow you to accomplish this in the next Assets release, which is currently in active development.

I don't have an ETA for you, but we are working on it

Comment: Thanks - that sounds good! I've had my eye on this for a while as have been using a matrix/safecracker file solution for a while and, frankly, it's just not as good a solution as I know you guys would come up with!

Comment: Hiya! This post is 2 years old now. Wondering if you could tell me if this is possible now in the latest version of Assets?

Comment: Ah, no, unfortunately that did not make the new and exciting feature list. You can, though, upload with simple HTML upload (http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/templating/channel_form.html) and accomplish the rest with a custom plugin - it shouldn't be too hard.